# match particular value from a group of values in excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I will explain my question using example.

I have a list of values like following:

```
cat1--val1
a-----x
a-----y
a-----z
b-----x
b-----y
b-----z
```

Output should be:

```
cat1--x---y
a---yes--yes
b---yes--yes
c---no---no
```

This is not working with vlookup. Pivoting is an option but that will be a lengthy process. Is there any excel formula to map a specific value directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, `=COUNTIFS()` is an option. Like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet2!B$1)>0,"yes","no")
```

Assuming your first table is on `Sheet1` and you are using `Sheet2` for output.

Comment: yes the tables are on different sheets...but you have to match a with a and b with b....like vlookup...but here there are multiple values for a or b and we need to lookup only specific values i.e x or y...

Comment: The formula pulls `x` and `y` from the top row (`Sheet2!B$1`).